# pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] during deploy of a Flask API on Render

Tags: python, flask, deployment

I'm trying to deploy a Flask Api on Render (render.com) and I am getting the error:

> pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)").

My code works running as a local host (my database is local), but not when I'm trying to deploy the API.
The code looks like:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import pyodbc
from flask_pydantic_spec import FlaskPydanticSpec
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
spec = FlaskPydanticSpec('flask', title="Endpoints da api de consulta \
                         da Base Nacional Curricular Comum - BNCC")

spec.register(app)
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})  

data_for_connection = (
    "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
    "Server=DESKTOP-1698A6Q\SQLEXPRESS;"
    "Database=bncc;"
    "Trusted_connection=YES;"
)
connection = pyodbc.connect(data_for_connection)
cursor = connection.cursor()

@app.route('/diario/aluno/<id_student>', methods=['GET'])
def list_student_by_id(id_student):
    "Lista os dados de um estudante pelo id"
    db = cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM tabela_alunos where id_aluno = ?", (id_student,))
    query_data = db.fetchone()  # Use fetchone() to retrieve a single row

    if query_data is not None:
        student_data = {
            "nome": query_data[0],
            "sobrenome": query_data[1],
            "nome_completo": query_data[2],
            "ano": query_data[3],
            "nivel_ensino": query_data[4],
            "idade": query_data[5],
            "cpf": query_data[6],
            "turma": query_data[7],
            "id_aluno": query_data[8],
            "status_aluno": query_data[9]
            # "data_cadastro_aln": query_data[10]
        }
        return jsonify(data=student_data, message="Aluno solicitado")
    else:
        return jsonify(message="Aluno não encontrado"), 404
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

My ProcFile is set like this:

> web: gunicorn main:app

And my requirements.txt like this:

```
blinker==1.7.0
click==8.1.7
colorama==0.4.6
Flask==3.0.0
Flask-Cors==4.0.0
flask-pydantic-spec==0.5.0
gunicorn==21.2.0
inflection==0.5.1
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
packaging==23.2
pydantic==1.10.13
pyodbc==4.0.39
typing_extensions==4.8.0
Werkzeug==3.0.1
```

[image]

I tried to install different versions of pyodbc, but still doesn't work when I try to deploy it.
Is this happening because I have a local database?

Comment: Look at `Server=DESKTOP-1698A6Q\SQLEXPRESS`, you sure the server backend can connect to this server. In your server, you can ping or curl by this url?

Comment: It works perfectly in local host. It's an api with several endpoints, a RestApi. I can use all the methods using Postman, for example (delete, post, get, put). The full code is here, if you don't mind: https://github.com/carlosjuniorcosta1/api_bncc_nuvem . Thanks, anyway.

Comment: This error don't come from your code, It become the lib from os. In your local, you installed the driver ODBC for your OS. But in the server, it clean. Try to install driver ODBC for your server by `sudo apt install msodbcsql17`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=alpine18-install%2Calpine17-install%2Cdebian8-install%2Credhat7-13-install%2Crhel7-offline

Comment: I have odbc for windows in my computer (odbc 17). I don't get what you mean by having it in the server too, as my database server it is local. I tested the connection in source data administrator on Windows (user DNs, System DNS). The connection was successfull, but still the same error during the deploy on Render.com.

Comment: In your server at render.com, `pyodbc` only python lib interface for easy calling to the driver msodbcsql. So, you need install driver msodbcsql17 for the render.com VM

Comment: You can read https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Install  at `Installing on Linux`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but I don't find a way to install the driver on Render.com (I already have it on Windows) and this post you sent me don't help in any way. The command `pip install pyodbc`, for whatever version it is pyodbc, still produces the same error on deploying. Trying to use a wheel instead , with `pip install pyodbc-5.0.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl` raises an error too (`ERROR: pyodbc-5.0.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`). It seems there is no solution until now on this matter for Windows. I don't have Linux here.